# Postfix configuration on DB

Tags: postfix, email-server, rocky-linux

I'm working on the migration of mailservers and in the meantime I've to manage a big configuration on my Postfix system on a Rocky Linux 8.5.
I know Postfix can handle configuration stored on MySQL, but I didn't find anything about the configuration of sender_dependent_relayhost_maps and canonical_maps parameters on a DB.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every configuration where the [postfix configuration manual](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#canonical_maps) instructs you to *"specify zero or more "type:name" lookup tables, separated by whitespace or comma."* can be used with [database lookups](https://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html). If you are migrating between different lookups, be very careful about considering which implicit properties of one lookup need to be explicitly expressed in another (search order, wildcards, ..)

While not all lookups/features are available in all places, Postfix would tell you on startup if you tried some unsupported combination.